# MDX multi-currency field involving All member

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am interested in getting some help regarding my mdx queries.

I wanted to have a field that is multi-currency. I was able to allow the user to aggregate if the currency was same.

```
SCOPE [Measures].[Base Gross Amount]; 
    This = 
    iif([Measures].[Measures].[MaximumCurrencyID] = [Measures].[Measures].[MinimumCurrency ID], [Measures].[Base Gross Amount], "Multiple Currencies");    

End Scope;
```

However, now the user also wants to display the appropriate currency format. So when I added another scope statement to format the measure, this works for the leaves but not for the All member, it just adds the word "All" to the formatting, any thoughts how can I get the descendants?

```
SCOPE ([Company Organization].[Order Company ID].members, [Measures].[Base Gross Amount] );
        Format_String(this) = [Company Organization].[Symbol].currentmember.Member_Value + "#,#.##";
    End Scope;
```

Comment: does changing the scope to `SCOPE([Company Organization].members,...` help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be originating here: `[Company Organization].[Symbol]`.

Can you set the `[Symbol]` hierarchy so it has no `All` member: in a similar way that the measures hierarchy has no All member.